# Ubuntu MATE 18.04 SD integrated card reader doesn't work in Lenovo N22

Tags: lenovo, sd-card

I have Lenovo N22 with integrated micro SD reader. It works under Windows, but doesn't recognize any card in Ubuntu MATE 18.04.

Additional informations:

- SD reader works under Windows
- Card is detected in Ubuntu when I use external SD->usb adapter

---

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b582 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

```
$ lspci -v 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 35) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 117
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 119
    Memory at 91314000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SD Controller (rev 35) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SD Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at 91315000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller (rev 35) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 116
    I/O ports at 1060 [size=32]
    Memory at 9131a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 35) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 115
    Memory at 91300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 120
    Memory at 91200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 91100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_txe
    Kernel modules: mei_txe

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Memory at 91310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 35) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: 91400000-915fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000091600000-00000000917fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #3 (rev 35) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: 91000000-910fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at 9131a800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    I/O ports at 1040 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
    Memory at 91000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`lspci` shows something about SD controller

```
    00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SD Controller (rev 35) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SD Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at 91315000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
```

`sudo dmesg | tail` after inserting sd card doesn't show anything

```
$ sudo dmesg | tail
[   14.785024] audit: type=1400 audit(1525684358.592:39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" name="/usr/share/cups/locale/" pid=737 comm="cups-browsed" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   14.785032] audit: type=1400 audit(1525684358.592:40): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" name="/usr/share/locale/" pid=737 comm="cups-browsed" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   15.681621] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   15.681632] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   15.681648] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   16.700951] IPv6: wlp2s0: IPv6 duplicate address 2407:7000:8d23:3a00::2 used by 44:00:10:bb:4e:28 detected!
[  177.745385] sdhci-pci 0000:00:12.0: SDHCI controller found [8086:2296] (rev 35)
[  227.834640] sdhci-pci 0000:00:12.0: SDHCI controller found [8086:2296] (rev 35)
[ 1183.952580] perf: interrupt took too long (2627 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 76000
[ 1538.709501] perf: interrupt took too long (3303 > 3283), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 60500
```

I've seen couple articles with similar problem. The solution was to reinstall `usdisks2` and reboot computer. I did it and nothing changed.

Please help me if you have any idea :)

Comment: I have the same problem in KUbuntu 18.04